# Поддержка аттрибута placeholder тэгом input в IE 6-8

Tags: jquery, javascript

Хочу сделать поддержку аттрибута placeholder тэгом input в Internet Explorer 6-8 с помощью файла jquery.placeholder.js. Но что-то не работает, подскажите в чем ошибка?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Регистрация</title>
        <link href="/bookshop/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bookshop/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bookshop/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function()
            {
                function hasPlaceholderSupport()
                {
                    var i = document.createElement('input');
                    return 'placeholder' in i;
                }

                if(!hasPlaceholderSupport())
                {
                    $("#create_account").placeholder();
                    //END placeholder_fallback

                    $('input[autofocus=true]').focus();
                };
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="create_account" action="registration.php" method="POST">
            <fieldset id="singup">
                <legend>Создайте новый аккаунт</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <laber for="firstname">Имя:</label>
                        <input id="firstname" type="text" autofocus="true" name="firstname" placeholder="John">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <laber for="lastname">Фамилия:</label>
                        <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Smith">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <laber for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="user@eample.com" autocomplete="off">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <laber for="password">Пароль:</label>
                        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="8-10 символов">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <laber for="password_confirm">Повторите пароль:</label>
                        <input id="password_confirm" type="password" name="password_confirm" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите пароль еще раз">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться">
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

jquery.placeholder.js

```
function ($) {
    $.fn.placeholder = function () {
        function valueIsPlaceholder(input) {
            return ($(input).val() == $(input).attr("placeholder"));
        }
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).find(":input").each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("type") == "password") {
                    var new_field = $("<input type='text'>");
                    new_field.attr("rel", $(this).attr("id"));
                    new_field.attr("value", $(this).attr("placeholder"));
                    $(this).parent().append(new_field);
                    new_field.hide();

                    function showPasswordPlaceholder(input) {
                        if ($(input).val() == "" || valueIsPlaceholder(input)) {
                            $(input).hide();
                            $('input[rel=' + $(input).attr("id") + ']').show();
                        };
                    };

                    new_field.focus(functon() {
                        $(this).hide();
                        $('input#' + $(this).attr("rel")).show().focus();
                    });

                    $(this).blurfuncton() {
                        showPasswordPlaceholder(this, false);
                    });

                showPasswordPlaceholder(this);

            } else {

                //Значение заменяется заполняюшим текстом.
                //Необязательный параметр reload решает проблему
                //кэширования полей в FF и IE.
                function showPlaceholder(input, reload) {
                    if ($(input).val() == "" || (reload && valueIsPlaceholder(input))) {
                        $(input).val($(input).attr("placeholder"));
                    }
                };

                $(this).focus(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
                        $(this) val("");
                    };
                });

                $(this).blur(function () {
                    showPlaceholder($(this), false)
                });

                showPlaceholder(this, true);
            };
            });

        //Заполняющийся текст не должен отправляться формой
        $(this).submit(function () {
            $(this).find(":input").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
                    $(this).val("");
                }
            });
        });
        });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: возник вопрос в первой строчке return ($(input).val() == $(input).attr("placeholder"))

Comment: Можете объяснить, что не так в этой строчке кода? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Все, наконец-то, заработало! Тему можно закрывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делайте просто так $('[placeholder]').placeholder();

Comment: Спасибо, кстати, найти ошибки помог firebug! Отличная вещь, всем рекомендую установить и пользоваться! www.firebug.ru

Answer (score 0):

Та же проблема была. Он не работает с jQuery 1.7 (ну по крайней мере точно с 1.7.2). Знаю что работает с 1.5.4, на Гитхабе еще лежит для 1.6.4, но он тоже не работает по 1.7.2. Так что или ищи другой плагин, или ставь подходящую версию jQuery.

Comment: У меня работает с jQuery 1.7.2, после того как я пофиксил все ошибки в коде)

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочая версия кода на jQuery:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.placeholder = function()
    {
        function valueIsPlaceholder(input)
        {
            return ($(input).val() == $(input).attr("placeholder"));
        }
        return this.each(function()
        {
            $(this).find(":input").each(function()
            {
                if($(this).attr("type") == "password")
                {
                    var new_field = $("<input type='text'>");
                    new_field.attr("rel", $(this).attr("id"));
                    new_field.attr("value", $(this).attr("placeholder"));
                    $(this).parent().append(new_field);
                    new_field.hide();

                    function showPasswordPlaceholder(input)
                    {
                        if($(input).val() == "" || valueIsPlaceholder(input))
                        {
                            $(input).hide();
                            $('input[rel=' + $(input).attr("id") + ']').show();
                        };
                    };

                    new_field.focus(function()
                    {
                        $(this).hide();
                        $('input#' + $(this).attr("rel")).show().focus();
                    });

                    $(this).blur(function()
                    {
                        showPasswordPlaceholder(this, false);
                    });

                    showPasswordPlaceholder(this);

                    }else{

                        //Значение заменяетсязаполняюшим текстом.
                        //Необязательный параметр reload решает проблему
                        //кэширования полей в FF и IE.

                        function showPlaceholder(input, reload){
                            if($(input).val() == "" || (reload && valueIsPlaceholder(input)))
                            {
                                $(input).val($(input).attr("placeholder"));
                            }
                        };

                        $(this).focus(function()
                        {
                            if($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder"))
                            {
                                $(this).val("");
                            };
                        });

                        $(this).blur(function()
                        {
                            showPlaceholder($(this), false)
                        });

                        showPlaceholder(this, true);
                    };
                });

                //Заполняющийся текст не должен отправляться формой
                $(this).submit(function()
                {
                    $(this).find(":input").each(function()
                    {
                        if($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder"))
                        {
                            $(this).val("");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        };

    })(jQuery);
```